Named symbol not found when use cupy to invoke cuda kernel
This is my cuda kernel: https://pastebin.com/ti95Qy2p, and I want to invoke compute_linear_recurrence method in this kernel.
But when I use code:
import cupy as cp
# code_str is code in https://pastebin.com/ti95Qy2p
calc_kernel = cp.RawKernel(code_str, 'compute_linear_recurrence', backend='nvcc')

to calculate results, it crashed with cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND: named symbol not found.
And not only compute_linear_recurrence, but also other methods in this cuda kernel can't be invoked.
So what happened and how to resolve it? This problem can't help me.

compute_linear_recurrence is a host function which runs on CPU. RawKernel or RawModule can only be used to invoke CUDA kernels.

This file has already been cuda kernel. So how to let compute_linear_recurrence run on GPU？Are there any other step I don't know？
